# Scheme Macro for nesting expressions

Tags: scheme, macros, nested, define-syntax

Can a macro be written in Scheme (with `define-syntax`, for example) which will take expressions like this:

```
(op a b c d e f g h i j)
```

And yield expressions like this as output?

```
(op (op (op (op (op (op (op (op (op a b) c) d) e) f) g) h) i) j)
```

Of course, for arbitrary lengths. I can't think of a way to do it, given some template like this:

```
(define-syntax op
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_) 'base-case]
    [(v1 v2 ...) 'nested-case??]))
```

Comment: I am curious. Was this just a question of theoretical interest or do you have an interesting use case? In general, that kind of wrapping would be achieved by a foldLeft.

Comment: hmm, good point. i mostly asked this because i didn't think of your way =P. i didn't realize this is exactly what foldl does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(define bop list)

(define-syntax op
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((op a b) (bop a b))
    ((op a b c ...) (op (bop a b) c ...))))
```

For example, `(op 1 2 3 4)` expands to `(bop (bop (bop 1 2) 3) 4)` and evaluates to `(((1 2) 3) 4)`.

Comment: Why are you using bop in the literal identifiers if you are not matching it?

Comment: scheme macros are really really smart with their ... aren't they?

Answer (score 1):

The function you want to apply to the arguments should itself be an argument to the macro. Barring that, my solution was the same.

```
#!r6rs

(import (rnrs base))

(define-syntax claudiu
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((claudiu fun first second)
     (fun first second))
    ((claudiu fun first second rest ...)
     (claudiu fun (claudiu fun first second) rest ...))))
```

Answer (score 0):

To show how the answer works out:

```
(op 1 2 3 4)
```

This is an op with 4 statements, so the 2nd case gets selected with a=1, b=2, c=3, ...=4:

```
(op (bop 1 2) 3 4)
```

This is an op with 3 statements, so 2nd case again. a=(bop 1 2), b=3, c=4:

```
(op (bop (bop 1 2) 3) 4)
```

Now this is a bop with 2 statements, so a=(bop (bop 1 2) 3), b=4, and it's done.