# Define-Syntax Arguments and Usage

Tags: scheme, define-syntax

I don't really understand the arguments and usage of define-syntax within Scheme. For what it's worth, I'm using Petite Chez Cheme. I've looked at a few sources:

[define-syntax issue in scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205002/define-syntax-issue-in-scheme)

[Scheme Macro for nesting expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340204/scheme-macro-for-nesting-expressions/340294#340294)

http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pattern-macros.html

However, they haven't given me the understanding I'm looking for. I'm looking for an explicit explanation of what's happening when the new syntax is applied. I'm particularly curious about the use of ellipses ("...") when the syntax is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a detailed document about patterns and define-syntax through a little bit more search. If anybody else is curious, here is the link:
http://www.cs.uml.edu/~giam/91.531/Textbooks/RKDybvig.pdf